# $x_{n+1}=(x_n +a)/2$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n =a$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

**The problem:**

Let $a \in R$ and $x_n$ a sequence in real numbers so that $x_{n+1}=(x_n +a)/2$. Prove that $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n=a $.

I have tried to assume that it doesn't converge to $a$, but I think it only creates a harder problem. Also, I tried to prove it using the definition of convergence (as it is the way this problem should be solved), but I didn't make any significant progress.

Comment: What is $x_{n+1}-a$?

Comment: I will correct the problem,I just saw it was incorrect

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$x_{n+1}-a=\dfrac12(x_n-a)=\dfrac{1}{2^n}(x_1-a)$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$|x_{n+1}-a|=(1/2)|x_n-a|$$ 
Thus $$|x_{n+1}-a|=(1/2)^n|x_1-a|\to 0$$

Answer (score 2):

If $x_n$ is convergence, say to $x$ then $$x=\lim _{n\to \infty}x_{n+1}=\lim _{n\to \infty}(x_n +a)/2=(x+a)/2.$$